# Gmail API Watch Request Not Filtering Label IDs

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

**Issue**

Trying to get the Gmail API to send only new messages to Cloud Pub/Sub by using the Gmail APIs Watch function but when setting the labelIds in order to filter to just INBOX, i am still notified of all changes, files sent, drafts etc.

I've looked online and can see that there are people that are experiencing this issue and there is even a bug out for it https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36759803.

But i find it kind of odd that the entire feature of filtering just doesn't work and its been an issue for 5 years according to the bug report. Makes me think its just me that is doing something wrong. Would be cool to hear from anyone that has got this to work.

**Where im at**

I'm using the Gmail API, trying to get my Gmail account to publish messages to Cloud Pub/Sub. I've managed to do this however im trying to filter what i get notifications for to just new messages. This is where i have a problem.

According to this Gmail API [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push#python), it appears all i have to call is the code below and that should be that. I will add however, that im calling the Kotlin equivalent, but i don't think this should matter.

```
request = {
  'labelIds': ['INBOX'],
  'topicName': 'projects/myproject/topics/mytopic'
}
gmail.users().watch(userId='me', body=request).execute()
```

What im calling:

```
val request = WatchRequest().apply {
    labelIds = listOf("INBOX")
    topicName = "projects/myproject/topics/mytopic"
}

gmail.users().watch("me", request).execute()
```

**Other things ive tried**

I have tried adding labelFilterAction = Include and other variations but they all seem to be ignored.

Comment: Still very much a bug in the API from my experience (trying to watch only on UNREAD message labelIds). The issue link still seems active so I think it very much is still a legit issue that just has not been addressed.

Answer (score 2):

After trying the ideas listed by ziganotschka, I'm more confident that the issue is not related to specific client libraries.

I managed to speak to someone at Google who in turn contacted the G-mail API team. They said they were aware that this is an issue, that it has been an issue since 2015 and was most likely caused by a change they made back then.

A ticket is still open, but doesn't look like it will be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

### Perform the following trouble-shooting actions

1. Provide a request body including `labelIds`, `labelFilterAction` AND `topicName` as specified [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users/watch)
2. Try the label `"UNREAD"` instead of `"INBOX"`
3. To discart Kotlin implementation related issues, test your request in a programming language that allows you to pass the request as a JSON body in exactly the same way as specified in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @ziganotschka. Tried all of your points and used Python, however still the same result, so it doesn't appear that this is an issue with client libraries.